# git svn clone in chunks and combine

Tags: git

When doing a clone on large repositories, git slows down considerably during the clone as the number of revisions checked out increases.  When using git svn clone, i can specify the revisions that i want to checkout.

```
git svn clone -rXX:YY url
```

For large repositories, i can checkout first 50000 revisions; and separately, i can checkout 50001 to 100000.  Later i want to combine the two clones into one that contains revisions 1 to 100000.  Is this/How is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at [git-replace](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace).

Answer (score 1):

Git supports the notion of a "shallow" clone that you can deepen over time.  However, unlike svn, revisions cannot be treated serially / sequentially.  A shallow clone starts from a particular named revision—a branch or tag name—and traverses the commit DAG to the specified `--depth`:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch $BRANCH $URL
```

for instance (replace `$BRANCH` and `$URL` with appropriate strings, and of course you can use a number larger than 1).  Use `git fetch` to deepen the clone; see [its documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for details.

You will need a relatively modern git (preferably at least 2.0; shallow clones go back further but the older you go, the less well they work).

Combining separate shallow clones is generally not the right way to go since you're doing graph traversal and you will be *extremely* likely to repeatedly traverse many of the same nodes this way (resulting in much more network, disk, and CPU usage) than by simply deepening or unshallowing a single clone.